# Bash Conditional Statements

Tags: bash, scripting

What are the three formats of conditional statements used in bash scripting?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: yes :( i'm not sure if they mean different if statements or are there other things as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [relevant section of the bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) lists 5 different constructs which can be used for conditional evaluation.  Of these, the `if`, `case`, and `[[ .. ]]` constructs are probably the most commonly used in real-world code, though the `(( .. ))` construct will get used frequently in scripts that do complex counting or other numerical operations.

But they don't mention another very common form used for branching in bash, which is to just execute a command in combination with short-circuit evaluation, for example

```
grep -q needle haystack.txt && echo "Needle located!" || echo "No dice or needles.";
```

`&&` and `||` are logical operators: "and" and "or" respectively.

This is effectively the same as

```
if grep -q needle haystack.txt; then echo "yea"; else echo "nay"; fi;
```

but works differently: in the first form, the conditional logic really comes about as a side effect of the actual explicit goal of the code, which is, at least ostensibly, to evaluate the logical operators.  This sort of construct is also commonly seen in C and JavaScript code.

It works by taking shortcuts: the parts of the expression, e.g. `x && y || z`, are evaluated left-to-right.  If the left side of a logical and, e.g. the `x` in `x && y`, evaluates to false, `bash` doesn't bother evaluating the `y` part because at that point it already knows that `x && y` is false.

The converse is true for logical ors: `true || z` always evaluates to true, no matter what z turns out to be.

So if the `grep` comes out false, `bash` can skip that first `echo`, because that part of the expression can't possibly be true.  So it moves on to the second `echo`.  On the other hand, if the grep is true, the first `echo` is executed (resulting in those words being, well, echoed..).  At this point `bash` is done, because whatever the value of the right-hand side of the `||`, the result of the expression will still be true.

To get a feel for the way bash works with conditionals, it's best to do some experimentation on the command line.  The command

```
echo $?;
```

will echo the *return code* of the previous statement.  This is an error code, so `0` means true, and a non-zero value means false.  It's a bit confusing at first, but you get used to it.

So you can do, for example

```
$ (( 1 + 2 == 3 )); echo $?
0
$ (( 1 + 2 == 4 )); echo $?
1
```

and perform similar tests with the `[[ .. ]]` construct to get a feel for these basic building blocks.  Once you've got that done, move on to `if` and then `case` statements.

As for the answer to your question, well, I think that's very dependent on the context it was asked in.  But getting a good understanding of the various options should help you figure out what they are looking for there.